# Why is my <script> giving me an undefined error even though it is being called?

Tags: jquery, scope, coldfusion, cfml

I'm working on a .cfm file that searches for people within the database. The search form should populate a string of names once I start typing using 'onKeyUp', however it is giving me that my variable 'stearchy' is undefined.

I'm rather new to ColdFusion manipulating DOM Elements, but I think its a matter of the scope because its just not reading it. The following that I've tried is: 
Place the onKeyUp below the function.

Any help in the right direction would be great. Below is the var code:

```
var stearchy = function() {
  while ( document.getElementById("daGuess").options.length ) document.getElementById("daGuess").options[0] = null;
  nam = [];
  hs = [];
  var boundLeft = document.getElementById("daSearch").value.indexOf(" ");
  if (boundLeft <= 0) var boundLeft = document.getElementById("daSearch").value.length;
  var boundRight = document.getElementById("daSearch").value.indexOf(" ")+1;
  <!--- if (boundRight == -1) var boundRight = 0; --->
  var ges = [];
  for ( i = 0; i < alums.length; i++ ) {            
    if (boundLeft > 0) {
      if ( document.getElementById("daSearch").value.search(/[A-Z][a-z]/) != -1) { 
        var noo = removeDiacritics(alums[i]["NameNickname"]).indexOf(removeDiacritics(document.getElementById("daSearch").value.slice(0,boundLeft)));
        var moo = removeDiacritics(alums[i]["NameFirst"]).indexOf(removeDiacritics(document.getElementById("daSearch").value.slice(0,boundLeft)));
        var loo = removeDiacritics(alums[i]["NameLast"]).indexOf(removeDiacritics(document.getElementById("daSearch").value.slice(boundRight,document.getElementById("daSearch").value.length)));
      /*Otherwise do a case-insensitive search*/
      } else {
        var noo = removeDiacritics(alums[i]["NameNickname"]).toLowerCase().indexOf(removeDiacritics(document.getElementById("daSearch").value.toLowerCase().slice(0,boundLeft)));
        var moo = removeDiacritics(alums[i]["NameFirst"]).toLowerCase().indexOf(removeDiacritics(document.getElementById("daSearch").value.toLowerCase().slice(0,boundLeft)));
        var loo = removeDiacritics(alums[i]["NameLast"]).toLowerCase().indexOf(removeDiacritics(document.getElementById("daSearch").value.toLowerCase().slice(boundRight,document.getElementById("daSearch").value.length)));
      }
      if (document.getElementById("daSearch").value.indexOf(" ") > 0 && document.getElementById("daSearch").value.indexOf(" ") < document.getElementById("daSearch").value.length-1) {
        if ( noo != -1 && loo != -1 ) { 
          ges[ges.length] = {tex:'"'+alums[i]["NameNickname"]+'"'+' '+alums[i]["NameFirst"]+' '+alums[i]["NameMiddle"]+' '+alums[i]["NameLast"].toUpperCase(),val:alums[i]["IDStudent"],nam:alums[i]["NameNickname"]+' '+alums[i]["NameLast"],hs:alums[i]["HS"]};
        }
        if ( moo != -1 && loo != -1 ) { 
          if(alums[i]["NameNickname"] != '') {
            ges[ges.length] = {tex:'"'+alums[i]["NameNickname"]+'"'+' '+alums[i]["NameFirst"]+' '+alums[i]["NameMiddle"]+' '+alums[i]["NameLast"].toUpperCase(),val:alums[i]["IDStudent"],nam:alums[i]["NameNickname"]+' '+alums[i]["NameLast"],hs:alums[i]["HS"]};
          } else {
            ges[ges.length] = {tex:alums[i]["NameFirst"]+' '+alums[i]["NameMiddle"]+' '+alums[i]["NameLast"].toUpperCase(),val:alums[i]["IDStudent"],nam:alums[i]["NameFirst"]+' '+alums[i]["NameLast"],hs:alums[i]["HS"]};
          }
        }
      } else {
        if ( noo != -1 ) { 
          ges[ges.length] = {tex:'"'+alums[i]["NameNickname"]+'"'+' '+alums[i]["NameFirst"]+' '+alums[i]["NameMiddle"]+' '+alums[i]["NameLast"].toUpperCase(),val:alums[i]["IDStudent"],nam:alums[i]["NameNickname"]+' '+alums[i]["NameLast"],hs:alums[i]["HS"]};
        }
        if ( moo != -1 ) { 
          if(alums[i]["NameNickname"] != '') {
            ges[ges.length] = {tex:'"'+alums[i]["NameNickname"]+'"'+' '+alums[i]["NameFirst"]+' '+alums[i]["NameMiddle"]+' '+alums[i]["NameLast"].toUpperCase(),val:alums[i]["IDStudent"],nam:alums[i]["NameNickname"]+' '+alums[i]["NameLast"],hs:alums[i]["HS"]};
          } else {
            ges[ges.length] = {tex:alums[i]["NameFirst"]+' '+alums[i]["NameMiddle"]+' '+alums[i]["NameLast"].toUpperCase(),val:alums[i]["IDStudent"],nam:alums[i]["NameFirst"]+' '+alums[i]["NameLast"],hs:alums[i]["HS"]};
          }
        }
        if (boundRight < document.getElementById("daSearch").value.length) {
          if ( loo != -1  ) { 
            if(alums[i]["NameNickname"] != '') {
              ges[ges.length] = {tex:'"'+alums[i]["NameNickname"]+'"'+' '+alums[i]["NameFirst"]+' '+alums[i]["NameMiddle"]+' '+alums[i]["NameLast"].toUpperCase(),val:alums[i]["IDStudent"],nam:alums[i]["NameNickname"]+' '+alums[i]["NameLast"],hs:alums[i]["HS"]};
            } else {
              ges[ges.length] = {tex:alums[i]["NameFirst"]+' '+alums[i]["NameMiddle"]+' '+alums[i]["NameLast"].toUpperCase(),val:alums[i]["IDStudent"],nam:alums[i]["NameFirst"]+' '+alums[i]["NameLast"],hs:alums[i]["HS"]};
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the onKeyUp function for the search form:

```
<cfif isDefined("form.RegGuest") OR isDefined("form.RegAlum")>
    Search: <input type="text" name="daSearch" value="" id="daSearch" onkeyup="stearchy()">

    <script> 
    document.getElementById("daSearch").focus();
    </script>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Instead of defining your function like this `var stearchy = function() {` try defining like this `function stearchy() {`.  See this reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/336868/1636917

Comment: Thank you for that! It's still giving me a reference error, but I understand why I would have used the latter and not the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be

```
<cfif isDefined("form.RegGuest") OR isDefined("form.RegAlum")>
    Search: <input type="text" name="daSearch" value="" id="daSearch" onkeyup="stearchy()">
    <cfoutput>
       <script type="text/javascript"> 
          document.getElementById("daSearch").focus();
       </script>
    </cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer:

I had an issue with a String Literal that didn't allow for the actual variable to work.

What it was before:

```
                    var alums = [<cfoutput query="Final">{NameNickname:"#Replace(Trim(NameNickname),"""","'","ALL")#",NameFirst:"#Replace(Trim(NameFirst),"""","'","ALL")#",NameMiddle:"#Replace(Trim(NameMiddle),"""","'","ALL")#",NameLast:"#Replace(Trim(NameLast),"""","'","ALL")#",Email:"#Trim(PhoneNumber)#",IDStudent:"#IDStudent#",HS:"#School_current#"}<cfif RecordCount NEQ CurrentRow>,</cfif></cfoutput>];
```

I had to change the Email string from a phone number, in order for it to read properly.

```
            var alums = [<cfoutput query="Final">{NameNickname:"#Replace(Trim(NameNickname),"""","'","ALL")#",NameFirst:"#Replace(Trim(NameFirst),"""","'","ALL")#",NameMiddle:"#Replace(Trim(NameMiddle),"""","'","ALL")#",NameLast:"#Replace(Trim(NameLast),"""","'","ALL")#",Email:"",IDStudent:"#IDStudent#",HS:"#School_current#"}<cfif RecordCount NEQ CurrentRow>,</cfif></cfoutput>];
```

However, I did change the var function and input the text/javascript, so that may have worked as well.

Thank you so much for the direction everyone!

Comment: Don't roll your own JSON ;-). Instead create an array of structures in CF and use something like [SerializeJSON](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/serializejson.html). It'll handle escaping automatically. (Has a few issues with booleans but should be ok for strings). Most browsers support `JSON.parse()` for deserializing it into JS objects.